# CodeIgniter Return value from a controller

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, return

I am calling this controller via Ajax:

```
class Landing extends CI_Controller 
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }


    function Index()
    {
        if ( $smt ){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

}
```

And the response comes back empty, though if replace :

```
return TRUE;
```

by

```
echo TRUE;
exit;
```

It works. I was wondering why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do an ajax call, the response is the HTML script that is returned from a URL. If you were to create an empty PHP file with

```
return TRUE;
```

it would show nothing to the user viewing the file, however

```
echo 'true';
```

would return a string. This is what your AJAX call picks up.